# An short exact sequence of $\mathfrak{g}$ of which head and tail are in category $\mathcal{O}$.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite-dimensional, semisimple Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $$ 0\rightarrow X  \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z \rightarrow 0 $$
be a short exact sequence of $\mathfrak{g}$-modules.

$\bf My \text{ } question:$ If $X,Z$ are in the category $\mathcal{O}$. Is it true that $Y$ in the category $\mathcal{O}$ as well?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Which $Y$ in the question should be a $Z$? The first one?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reminder!  You are right, I have modified it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The category $\mathcal{O}$ is closed under quotienting, submodules  and finite direct sums, but not under extensions. Hence $Y$ need not be in $\mathcal{O}$ in general (see [here](http://stanford.edu/~khare/EoM-BGG-O.pdf)).

Comment: That link just seems to say this, but does not actually give any example. How easy is it to construct one, and which of the properties can we make fail?

Comment: In Humphreys book "Representations of Semisimple Lie
Algebras in the BGG Category $\mathcal{O}$" there is an example, for $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$-modules, where $Y$ cannot lie in $\mathcal{O}$, see chapter $3$.